# Installing Wacom Bamboo drivers creates "No more handles" error in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, graphics-tablet, bamboo

Id like to use my Wacom Bamboo tablet for OneNote and GIMP but when I install the drivers for the graphics tablet my Eclipse throws the infamous "Unhandled event loop exception - no more handles". I know that the error only occurs with the tablet drivers installed, because they disappear when I uninstall the drivers.

I think this has to do with some kind of overlay that allows input with the graphics tablet. This is why I tried to install the driver manually.

I extracted files from the installer, (pentablet_5.3.5-3.exe, can be downloaded from the wacom drivers page) there are some .inf's in there but I don't know how to use them...

The folder inside the installer that could be helpful is this one:
http://i.gyazo.com/e904c107e3a5619a85fefd84ad86c0e2.png
and inside the "Drivers" folder you can find the .inf-Files:
http://i.gyazo.com/4eb227ec62b20759803e1910f3bc20a4.png

Any help is highly appreciated.